# Android - While building project

Tags: android, compiler-errors, android-resources, androidx, android-instant-run

When I'm building my project, it's giving me this error, How can I solve it?

**Error**

> "instant_run_split_apk resources"

I tried :

- cleaning project and
- invalidating cache

Comment: can you post the full description of the error? Chances are you won't get it if you disable instant run (Android studio-> preferences -> build,execution,deployment ->instant run

Comment: I have the same problem.  Any resolution besides turning off Instant Run?

Answer (score 0):

Disabling **Instant Run** will help, this error will hide.

[image]